# How to push data to arrays which are inside of an object with React Hooks?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to make some charts where the data has to be coming in in real time over a web socket. I am working with React and Hooks, and I am not sure where I am making a mistake with my syntax. I need to have the two axes be different arrays, this is usually used for graphing parametric data.

```js
  const [Chartdata, setData] = useState({              
    Analog1: [],
    Analog2: []
  });     

  // 1. listen for a socket event and update the state.
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('Ana', data => {
      setData({
        
        Analog1: *Analog1*.push(data.Ana1),
        Analog2: *Analog2*.push(data.Ana2)
        }
      );
    
    });
  
  }, []);
```

I get this error stating that Analog1 and Analog2 (in between asterisks for highlighting purposes) are not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties `Analog1` and `Analog2` are part of the `Chartdata` state, and can't be accessed outside of it. So to push something into `Analog1`, you'll need to use`Chartdata.Analog1.push()`.

However, React doesn't didn't mutations to objects an arrays (push for example), so you'll need to create a new `Chartdata` object with new `Analog1` and `Analog2` properties. To do so, use [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) when setting the state, create a new object, and use spread or concat to create new arrays with the new values:

```
const [Chartdata, setData] = useState({              
  Analog1: [],
  Analog2: []
});     

// 1. listen for a socket event and update the state.
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('Ana', data => {
    setData(({ Analog1, Analog2 }) => ({       
      Analog1: [...Analog1, data.Ana1],
      Analog2: [...Analog2, data.Ana2]
    }));
  });

}, []);
```